# How to backup vuforia unty project smallest size?

Tags: unity-game-engine, backup, vuforia

How the best way to backup vuforia project smallest size in the best way.
Thanks

I tried backup Assets and Project Setting Folder, but vuforia not recognized in when im open backup project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also backup the `Packages` folder, besides `Assets` and `ProjectSettings`.

The Packages folder contains the `manifest.json` file that describes all packages you use in your project. If you don't have it, packages will be missing in your project.